# Angular Service shared between Library and Application

Tags: angular

I have built an Angular library including a component. I'm using this library component in my application project. I would like to send data from the application to the library component using a shared service.

The service is 'providedIn' root to make it singleton.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogMonitorService implements OnDestroy {
...
}
```

I inject this service into the library component (standalone) and into the app component of my project. Unfortunately, the service does not work as expected. It seems, there are two instances created for the service. One for the app and another one for the library. Thus, it is not possible to exchange date between the application and the library component.

Does anybody know how I can create a single instance?

The lib component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-log-monitor',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  providers: [LogMonitorService],
  templateUrl: './log-monitor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./log-monitor.component.css']
})
export class LogMonitorComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private service = inject(LogMonitorService);
  private subscription: Subscription | undefined;

  public items: String[] = [];

  constructor() {
        this.subscription = this.service.observable.subscribe({
      next: (val) => {
        this.items = val;
      },
    })
  }
}
```

The app.module:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    LogMonitorComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The app.component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private logMenuPanel = inject(LogMonitorService);

  constructor() { }
}
```

Regards Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove this service from all `providers: [LogMonitorService],`.

In your case you have 3 instances of the service. 1st because of `provideIn: 'root'` and it is created in the root injector (not really created, but it would be created if injected). 2nd because of `LogMonitorComponent` `providers` and the 3rd from `AppModule` `providers`.

Comment: I removed the providers from the library component and deleted the 'provideIn' in the service class. Then I got a `NullInjectorError` in the browser. Thus, I needed to add `providers: [LogMonitorService],` to the app.module.ts. Now It works as expected. Many Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelNeumair I would rather leave the `provideIn: 'root'` instance in your case. It is the most obvious one that the service should be used as a singleton and in case you don't use it anywhere in the app, it won't be even included into the bundle.